# how to delete wordpress plugin permenetly?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

After deleting a plugin on WP and reinstall it, I keep finding the old info that I've saved before, is there a way I can Install that plugin like it's the first time?

Comment: You'll get more mileage on [Wordpress.se].

Comment: The wordpress plugin may have saved some information in database. You need to find them and delete them in database.

Comment: which table can I find this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For deleting a plugin you have to do these things.

> 1.Delete it from dashboard(you have done this)
>
> 2.Access your Wordpress files using FTP then go to plugin folder and delete the relevant plugin folder.
>
> 3.Now delete it from Database. Open Mysql and delete plugin table if it is not there then delete it from  wp_options.

That's it.